# Stored procedure suddenly using multiple execution plans in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012, stored-procedures, execution-plan

We have a commonly utilized stored procedure that had been functioning properly, but it unexpectedly began utilizing several plans (as many as 20, according to the performance analyzer) and causing a lot of blocking. The wait activity associated with it was PAGEIOLATCH_SH. This lasted for an hour (at night when no one uses our application) before reverting to its typical plan usage during the day. What could have caused this alteration?